# Use of extract in pipe: select numbers and put them into separate variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data.frame. One variable contains values like those c('Test11','Test12','Test21','Test22'). 
I would like to make two new variables out of this.
Var1 including the first number.
Var2 including the second number.

Something like:
data_Test %>%
  extract(Phase, c('Test','Order'), regex = "(.[[:digit:]])-([[:digit:]])" )

I know it is simple question. But i am not very familiar with regex. All those ./:[ and so on...

Comment: Is the word `Test` actually `Test` or just any character string?

Comment: It is always 'Test'.

Comment: OK. I just edited my answer to work with any character string. But my initial answer (with `Test` instead of `[[:alpha:]]*`) was fine enough then

Comment: I just edited back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_Test$Var1 <- gsub("Test(\\d)\\d", "\\1", data_Test$Phase)

data_Test$Var2 <- gsub("Test\\d(\\d)", "\\1", data_Test$Phase)
```

Comment: data_Test <- data_Test %>%
  mutate(Test = gsub("Test(\\d)\\d", "\\1", Phase))

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `sub` here for a base R option:

```
x <- c("Test11", "Test12", "Test21", "Test22")
out <- sub("^\\D+", "", x)
out

[1] "11" "12" "21" "22"
```